# Resize Gazebo 1.9.3 Window

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to resize horizontally the gazebo gui window in Gazebo 1.9.3?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5618/resize-gazebo-1.9.3-window/) by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on 2014-03-11**:
I have seen this fix but is after the 1.9.3 version https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/915/added-gui-configuration-via-ini-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Bon dia Martí:

You are right, the feature was implemented in pull request 915, but it is still not released, hosted in the default branch of the repository, to appear in the next major release of gazebo, the version 3.0. It breaks the API so it is not possible to backport it to previous series. So I'm afraid that you won't be able to use it in gazebo 1.9 series.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on 2014-03-12**:
Thanks Jose :)

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-03-12**:
You are welcome. Could you please mark the answer as correct so I won't have it pending under 'unanswered'? Thanks.